# C# Serial port event error

Tags: c#, serial-port

```
  while (!port.Readline())
        { 


        }
```

I am trying to read from the serial port if an event occurs. The above code is monitoring the even but when I am trying to compile it, it's giving me an error

> System.IO.Ports.SerialPort' does not contain a definition for 'Readline' and no extension method 'Readline' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I am unable to unable to understand the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use `port.ReadLine()` (with an uppper case L) since C# is case sensitive. But [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)s result type is string, not bool. Edit: Here's an example, how to use it correctly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline.aspx

Comment: I have to check for the boolean true condition. How do I do that?

Comment: You can define a bool variable an check for it. Of course you will have set it to false somewhere when you don't want to read data any longer. Or you could do something like `while(latestMessageReadAsString != "quit") { ... }`. Depends on your needs.

Comment: this bool variable will be set on some event but I am unable to understand how to check for this event?

Comment: Do you mean `while (yourBool) { ... }` or do you want to know how to handle the event to set `yourBool`? What event is it? Just have a look at the MSDN library page of your event to see some sample code how to handle it.